# Orientation change and Android VideoPlayer? What is going on?

Tags: android, orientation, android-music-player

I have the following code which searches a text file on my phone's sd card for the url of a song on a webserver.

I am able to shuffle the song by turning the phone to change the orientation and I do not understand where that logic is coming from.
Is this a default behavior for Video Player, because I don't see anything in my code that would cause a shuffle in this way.

What is causing it to shuffle like this?
If this is the case, what should I look into to turn this feature off?

I would like to keep both horizontal and vertical orientation so coding it to remain in one orientation is not what im after.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class MusicPlayerActivity extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "TestMus1.txt");

        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));
         LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(br);

          int min = 1;
          int max = 1618;
          Random r = new Random();
          int someRandomNo = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; 
          textView1.setText(Integer.toString(someRandomNo));
          rdr.setLineNumber(someRandomNo);
          int linenum = 0;
          String theLine = "";
          while (linenum < someRandomNo) {
              theLine = br.readLine();
              linenum++;
          }
          textView1.setText(theLine);

              VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);         
              MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
              mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
      // Set Audio
              Uri video = Uri.parse(theLine);
              videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
              videoView.setVideoURI(video);
              videoView.start();                                      
      }
      catch (Exception e) {   
         //Error Handling
      }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orientation change usually calls `onCreate()` again, and restarts the activity at a new configuration.

make sure you do the following:

**Set the Activity's manifest to intercept orientation change events**

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

**Override `onConfigurationChanged()`**

OrientationChange event will now call `onConfigurationChanged()` instead of `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

And read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html), it's a great document about faster orientation changing.

Comment: the link you've provided is broken :(